# How to sort document based on string order in elasticsearch6.8

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 6.8, I have below document:

```
{
   ...
   item: 'AAA',
   ...
},
{
   ...
   item: 'BBB',
   ...
},
{
   ...
   item: 'CCC',
   ...
}
```

And in the query request, there is a filter for the `item` field as shown below.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "item": [
              "BBB", "CCC"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Mike"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
```

What I want is to sort the matched document based on the item order in the request array. Take above as an example, it filters the document which have `BBB`, or `CCC` in their `item` field. I'd like to see the document with `BBB` has higher score than the document with `CCC` because users put `BBB` before `CCC` in the query request. How can I achieve this in Elasticsearch?

Comment: you basically want to get the query response sorted on the item field in lexographical order and in your case item is a multivalue ( array) field, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve scoring on the basis of creation date, you will need to add create_timestamp to each doc. (You can implement this using a pipeline. eg : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/creation-and-update-timestamps-for-each-doc/93456/2)

Once you have the create_timestamp, you can sort the results using the same. Here's how:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

To rescore documents using create_timestamp you can use "function_score" with  "field_value_factor" on date.
Here an example: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11872

Comment: I am not asking about how to sort timestamp. I am asking how to sort based on a requested string array.

Comment: That can be achieved using "Function_score" too , you ll need write a filter for each string. as shown here  : apply the function only if a document matches a given filtering query 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor

Comment: How can I pass the array of string into the function? I can only use some fixed value or formula on the score function right?

Comment: you can add the term value to your function, might be cumbersome for a long array though:

"functions": [
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "test": "bar" } },
                  "random_score": {}, 
                  "weight": 23
              },
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "test": "cat" } },
                  "weight": 42
              }
          ],